# Unauthorized 401 error for GET call on stockitem

Tags: spring, acumatica, resttemplate

I am accessing Acumatica API using Java Spring Resttemplate. The POST call to the Login endpoint works fine. But the next call to get StockItems gets a `401 Unauthorized error`.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:615) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:544) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:465) at
```

Now this works fine when I use Postman and the Chrome Restlet client. I noticed that in Restlet client the GET call to the API passes a session cookie that was set by the API in the login call. I tried passing the response headers from the login call in the GET request. But I still get a 401. I am using the standard resttemplate configuration.

```
HttpEntity<Credentials> entity = new HttpEntity<Credentials>(credentials, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://xxxx.acumatica.com/entity/auth/login", 
HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

HttpHeaders rHeaders = response.getHeaders();
String set_cookie = rHeaders.getFirst(rHeaders.SET_COOKIE);

if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) { LOG.info("Response: " + response.toString()); }
if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) { LOG.info("Set-Cookie: " + set_cookie); }


HttpEntity<String> entity2 = new HttpEntity<String>(response.getHeaders());
ResponseEntity<String> response2 = restTemplate.exchange("https://usell.acumatica.com/entity/Default/6.00.001/StockItem?$expand=Attributes,WarehouseDetails", HttpMethod.GET, entity2, String.class);
```

How did Acumatica API client using Java get around this problem?

Comment: it seems yuo are not passing all the needed credentials/headers/tokens to acumastica. Try to check your java call vs a working one

Comment: You were right.. All I had to do was create my request headers with all the cookies

Answer (score 2):

I was not setting all the cookies.. this is all I had to do

```
List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
for (String cookie : cookies) {
requestHeaders.add("Cookie", cookie);
}
```